# after a interval send different response from a rest endpoint url

Tags: java, rest, vert.x

There is one application which use to keep on polling some rest endpoint URL to get status after a specific interval. The rest API is waiting for some action to get complete. Till the time action won't get complete and application will hit the endpoint, this rest API send status as status in response as 'in progress'. once action will get complete rest API sends success as status in response.

I have challenge to mock this rest API as don't want to hit actual rest API for testing.

Is there any way to send different response from mock rest API after a interval when application will poll by hitting the endpoint?

I am using vertx with java for this.

Comment: i don't understand the setup. maybe if you posted some code showing an example of what you're trying to do then someone can give you further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specifically related to Vert.x, but still.

The trick here is not to count the interval, but the number of times this mock endpoint has been hit.

Here's a code to demonstrate how that should work:

```
private static final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
private static final HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(
        new HttpClientOptions()
                .setDefaultHost("localhost")
                .setDefaultPort(8443));
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger hitCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler((c) -> {
        if (hitCounter.incrementAndGet() >= 5) {
            c.response().setStatusCode(200).end();
        }
        else {
            c.response().setStatusCode(202).end();
        }
    }).listen(8443);

    System.out.println("Server started");

    callServerUntilSuccess();
}

public static void callServerUntilSuccess() {
    client.request(HttpMethod.GET, "/", (r) -> {
        if (r.statusCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("I'm done");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("I'll try again");
            vertx.setTimer(1000, (l) -> callServerUntilSuccess());
        }
    }).end();
}
```